# Visual Studio 2019 is too laggy to the point where it looks like time has stopped. So laggy that I pull PC cable out of the plug, and it's still on

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2019, lag

Ok, I don't think my computer is a cardboard box, it isn't that trash I guess. My CPU is not a quad-core. Well, getting straight to the point, I can't even use Visual Studio 2019 properly, it constantly crashes, and when I try to select an option in a project, it just freakin' lags. My CPU isn't even used to the 50%. What can I do to change this? Do I to sell my organs and buy a better PC or is there anything else I can do?

Specs :

- i3-6100
- 8 GB RAM
- Rx 470(I Guess the GPU doesn't even matter).

Comment: You can try disabling some features like autocompletion or other kinds of syntax checking. Your CPU won't be used much when You are just idling in the code window, but You can open the task manager in another window and start typing some code to see if the CPU usage increases. Also, You might want to consider some alternatives to Visual Studio, depending on what You need it for.

Comment: Do you run Visual Studio from an SSD or HDD?

Comment: HDD, but whatever, I'll be changing my PC to a better one and I'll buy an SSD. at this time, I'm using azure VPS.